# When calling a object function without the parenthesis, how could it display a custom message instead of returning entire function?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am creating a uniquely designed Javascript API called Javascript-X. Instead of using the conventional method to make an API, I am creating the whole API Inside of a single variable using an object tree.

This may look fine, "$jx.ex()" returns 'Hello World', However if you type "$jx.ex" it returns the entire function. Run the code snippet to see.

The question is, can you customize the message that displays when you type "$jx.ex"?

```js
$jx = {
  ex: function() {
    return ('Hello World.')
  }
};
console.log($jx.ex());
console.log($jx.ex.toString())
```

Comment: No. If you call `.ex` rather than `.ex()` you are asking for a function reference, not an invocation of the function, and that's what you get. The only way `.ex` would return the string would be if it was a property with the string as its value, not a pointer to a function.

Comment: I revised the question with your edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When calling a object function without the parenthesis, how could it display a custom message instead of returning entire function?

When *referencing* an object function without parentheses, unless you're using `new`, you're not **calling** it, you're just referencing it. E.g.:

```
// There are no function calls here
var x = $jx.ex;
```

If users of your API do the above, `x` will be a reference to the function, not a string.

> The question is, can you customize the message that displays when you type "$jx.ex"?

If you're doing this in the console and seeing the entire function, it may be that the console coerced to string (which calls `toString`), or it may be that the console did something at a lower level. If the former, we can override that by giving the function a new `toString`:

```js
$jx = {
  ex: function() {
    return ('Hello World.')
  }
};
$jx.ex.toString = function() {
    return "This is the custom 'message'.";
};
console.log($jx.ex());           // A call
console.log($jx.ex);             // Not a call, results will
                                 // vary from console to console
console.log($jx.ex.toString());  // toString directly
console.log(String($jx.ex));     // toString indirectly
```

Comment: You're a life-saver. If you don't mind my asking, can you add me on skype?

Comment: @AvenDyke: Sorry, best to keep things on-site.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below example :

```
function Multiply(operator, operand) {
    return operator * operand;
}

This could equally be written:

Multiply = function(operator, operand) {
    return operator * operand;
}
```

While in the first example, the implication may not be obvious, the second example shows more clearly that we're assigning a function which has 2 parameters to a variable called Multiply, and this concept of functions as assignments is common throughout javascript. This is a small demonstration of the fact that functions are "first class citizens", that is, they can be passed around exactly as if we were passing around values.

So now to the difference of assignment:

```
var operator = 3;
var operand = 4;
var ret = Multiply(operator, operand);
```

At the point of defining the ret variable, Multiply is executed and the return value is assigned - ret becomes equal to 12.

Lets try that again a different way:

```
var operator = 3;
var operand = 4;
var ret = Multiply;
```

Now, at the point of defining ret, ret becomes your Multiply function as opposed to being the result obtained from your Multiply function. Calls to ret() will cause your Multiply function to be executed, and you can call it exactly as if you'd called Multiply(operator, operand):

```
var out = ret(3, 4);
```

is the same as

```
var out = Multiply(3, 4);
```